# How to handle Carrierwave filename: nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, null, carrierwave

I am building a Ruby on Rails 5.1.6 app and working with Carrierwave. My goal is to list the filename next to the upload button

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    Upload a main image file <%= form.file_field :main_image, style: 'display:none;' %>
  </label>
    <% unless File.basename(@portfolio_item.main_image.path).nil? %>
       <%= File.basename(@portfolio_item.main_image.path) %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

I have been able to extract and show the filename using `File.basename(@portfolio_item.thumb_image.path)` and that works great as long as there is a file already there.

The issue is when on the `new.html.erb page`, I git an `no implicit conversion of nil into String` error because there is no file yet (thats the purpose of the new page).

I have tried

```
unless File.basename(@portfolio_item.main_image.path).nil?
  File.basename(@portfolio_item.main_image.path)
end
```

and some variations with a ternary statement, but they all come back with the same `no implicit conversion of nil into String` error.

my goal is for the to return a string: "select an image", if there no image.

I'm sure there is a simple way to handle this, I'm just overlooking it.

Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you. for future so searchers as well as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before pass image_path into `File.basename(..)`, check it whether image is present or not, if no then show a string `select an image..` , hopefully  this can resolve the issue.

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        Upload a main image file <%= form.file_field :main_image, style: 'display:none;' %>
      </label>
        <%= if @portfolio_item.main_image.present?%>
          <%= File.basename(@portfolio_item.main_image.path) %>
        <%else%>
          <p>select an image..</p>
        <%end%>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
if @portfolio_item.main_page?
  File.basename(@portfolio_item.main_image.path)
end
```